Why is structure needed in column generation?
I have a question about a problem in my Large Scale optimization course. The problem states that column generation can be used on linear problems with a common structure, and where all variables have a common interpretation. The question is, where in the column generation method this structure is important and why.
I have tried going through my lecture notes and searched on Google, but I cant find any clues that help me answer the question. The only guess that I have is that the structure is needed when calculating the reduced costs, but I am really unsure and would appreciate some help to find the answer.
